# Whats the difference between predicate and callback function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my code I am trying to learn.

```
let depList : Array<number>;
depList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

let numResults = depList.filter(num => num > 5); // predicate
console.log(numResults);

let resultFind = depList.find(num => num ==5); // predicate
console.log(resultFind);

let sum = depList.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num); // callback function
console.log(sum);
```

What's the difference betweeen predicate and callback function here?

I tried going through the method definition but seems hard to understand the differnece.

Comment: Predicate functions are functions that return a single TRUE or FALSE .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big overlap.

A "predicate" is a function that takes parameters and returns a boolean. It is always a boolean as it is always related to some logical check. Examples

```
const isEmpty = x => x.length === 0;
const isOdd   = n => n % 2 === 1;
const isEven  = n => n % 2 === 0;
```

A "callback" is any function that is passed in as a parameter. It might be a predicate (returning boolean) or not.

In the case of `.filter()` and `.find()` the *callback* they accept is a *predicate*.

A predicate needs not be used as a callback. And a callback needs not be a predicate. The two are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, a predicate is a pure function that returns a boolean describing it's arguments. Many languages and libraries specify that a predicate only requires one argument, but this is not true in javascript. A callback is a function that is passed to another function.

In typescript, predicates are significant because they can be used for type narrowing. For example:

```
const myArray:Array<null | number>();
...
const filtered = myArray.filter((n):n is number => n != null)
```

Because the predicate was annotated with `n is number`, it is now a type predicate. This means that `filtered` now has the type `number[]` - the type system knows that all the nulls have been filtered from the array.

Comment: Predicates may accept more than a single argument.